# Does the use keyword in PHP closures pass by reference?

Tags: php, function, functional-programming

For example, if I do this:

```
function bar(&$var)
{
    $foo = function() use ($var)
    {
        $var++;
    };
    $foo();
}

$my_var = 0;
bar($my_var);
```

Will `$my_var` be modified? If not, how do I get this to work without adding a parameter to `$foo`?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

No, they are *not* passed by reference - the `use` follows a similar notation like the function's parameters.

As written you achieve that by defining the `use` as pass-by-reference:

```
    $foo = function() use (&$var)
```

It's also possible to create recursion this way:

```
$func = NULL;
$func = function () use (&$func) {
    $func();
}
```

---

> **NOTE:** The following old excerpt of the answer (Jun 2012) was written for PHP < 7.0. As since 7.0 (Dec 2015) the semantics of `debug_zval_dump()` changed (different zval handling) the `refcount(?)` output of it differs nowadays and are not that much saying any longer (integers don't have a refcount any longer).
>
> Validation via the output by not displaying `$my_var` changed (from `0`) still works though (behaviour).

You can validate that on your own with the help of the [`debug_zval_dump`](http://php.net/debug_zval_dump) function ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CMSHY)):

```php
function bar(&$var)
{
    $foo = function() use ($var)
    {
        debug_zval_dump($var);
        $var++;
    };
    $foo();
};
    
$my_var = 0;
bar($my_var);
echo $my_var;
```

Output:

```
long(0) refcount(3)
0
```

A full-through-all-scopes-working reference would have a refcount of 1.

Comment: Better a year later than never!

Answer (score 21):

Closures are, almost by definition, closed by value, not by reference. You may "use by reference" by adding an `&` in the argument list:

```
function() use (&$var)
```

This can be seen in example 3 in the [anonymous functions manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Answer (score 4):

No, they are not passed by reference.

```
function foo(&$var)
{
    $foo = function() use ($var)
    {
        $var++;
    };
    $foo();
}

$my_var = 0;
foo($my_var);
echo $my_var; // displays 0

function bar(&$var)
{
    $foo = function() use (&$var)
    {
        $var++;
    };
    $foo();
}

$my_var = 0;
bar($my_var);
echo $my_var; // displays 1
```