# Assign the value from callback to variable?

Tags: php

I am having problem to assign the value from callback to variable.

Example code below, that work without any issue. It will display on the browser.

```
Service::connect($account)->exec(['something'], function ($line) {
   echo $line . PHP_EOL;
});
```

However, I want to assign to variable for json response.

This does not work:

```
$outout = null;

Service::connect($account)->exec(['something'], function ($line) use ($outout) {
      $outout = $outout . = $line;
);

echo $outout;
```

The `$outout` is still null.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the use keyword in PHP closures pass by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869572/does-the-use-keyword-in-php-closures-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `$outout` as a [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) if you want it to change outside the scope of your function. You do that by adding `&` in your function call.

```
$outout = '';
Service::connect($account)->exec(['something'], function ($line) use (&$outout) {
      $outout = $outout . = $line;
);
```

Comment: Yes, that is to inherit a variable from the parent scope, not the other way around. Look here for a reference http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass it as reference to change it value. Use an  `&` before your variable on `use` statement.

```
$outout = null;

Service::connect($account)->exec(['something'], function ($line) use (&$outout) {
      $outout = $outout . = $line;
);

echo $outout;
```