# Laravel eloquent chunk does not work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have tried the following in [laravel-5.4](/questions/tagged/laravel-5.4) application to use [`chunk`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#chunking-results):

```
$out = [];
\App\User::chunk(5,function($users) use($out){
   foreach($users as $user){
       //$out[] = $user;
       $out[] = $user->id;
   }
});
dd($out);
```

However, the output of `dd($out)` is still empty array. What's the problem here? `$out` is in global scope!

Comment: its not an issue with chunk, its a PHP thing ... arrays are copy on write unless told otherwise

Comment: @raina77ow it returns single item array as expected. i.e `array:1 [▼
  0 => 1
]`

Comment: Answered below, https://3v4l.org/IQsMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, `use` in PHP doesn't just make a variable from outer scope available within the function (similar to lexical scope in JS etc.). It *copies* the value of that variable (and [here's more explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10869632/1229023), for some reason still missing in the official doc).

Take `use` as a mean to pass some value inside the function without actually making it a formal parameter, a part of function's signature.

The bottom line is, you should pass the array as reference:

```
\App\User::chunk(5,function($users) use(&$out){
   foreach($users as $user){
       //$out[] = $user;
       $out[] = $user->id;
   }
});
```

Comment: Good explanation that fixes the scope concept clash! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are copy on write. You are just creating a new array in that scope when you try to write to the array you are trying to import from the parent scope.

You need to be using the reference to the array.

```
function ($users) use (&$out) { ... }
```

Comment: It works, but it breaks my understand about scope. Array is a variable, and it is defined in a global or parent scope, so logically, it should be updated with the new data in the child scope!!!

Comment: @SaidbakR dont confuse vars with classes, objects always pass by reference. https://3v4l.org/VXfm5

Comment: "As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object. When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of the identifier, which points to the same object."